# Filebeat service hangs on restart

Tags: logstash, aws-cloudformation, filebeat

I have some weird problem with `filebeat`

I am using cloud formation to run my stack, and a part of that i am installing and running `filebeat` for log aggregation,

I inject the `/etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml` into the machine and then i need to restart `filebeat`.

The problem is that `filebeat` hangs. and the entire provisioning is stuck (note that if i ssh into the machine and issue the "`sudo service filebeat restart` myself, the entire provisioning becomes unstuck and continues). I tried restarting it both via the `services` section and the `commands` section of the cloudformation::init and they both hang.

I havent tried it via the `userdata` but thats the worst possible solution for it.

Any ideas why?

snippets for the template. both these hang as mentioned.

> ```
> "commands" : {
>           "01" : {
>             "command" : "sudo service filebeat restart",
>             "cwd" : "~",
>             "ignoreErrors" : "false"
>           }
> }
> ```

```
"services" : {
          "sysvinit" : {
            "filebeat" : {
              "enabled" : "true",
              "ensureRunning" : "true",
              "files" : ["/etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml"]
            }
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, this does sound like some sort of lock.. According to the [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-init.html#aws-resource-init-services), you should insert a dependency to the `file`, in the filebeat service, under the `services` section, and that will cause the filebeat service restart you need.

Apparently, the `services` section supports a `files` attribute:

`A list of files. If cfn-init changes one directly via the files block, this service will be restarted.`

Comment: I did that and it hangs. When i restart the service via the userdata it works

Comment: hmmm... could you please update your question to add the relevant section from your current template that hangs?